# How to update table from linking table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I am using a PostgreSQL database and querying in the dark here. I have three (3) tables: `zip_code`, `zip_code_type`, and `temp_zip_type`. They have the following columns:

```
zip_code
  zip_5_digit text
  type_id     integer

zip_code_type
  id    integer
  value text

temp_zip_type
  temp_zip  text
  temp_type text
```

I am trying to UPDATE `zip_code` and SET `zip_code.type_id = zip_code_type.id` so that `zip_code.zip_5_digit` matches with `temp_zip_type.temp_zip`, and `temp_zip_type.temp_type` matches `zip_code_type.value`.

Here is my attempt:

```
UPDATE
    zip_code
SET
    type_id = 
    (
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            zip_code_type
        JOIN
            temp_zip_type
        ON
            temp_type = value
        WHERE
            temp_zip = zip_5_digit
    );
```

The result I am looking for is the `type_id` match the value in `zip_code_type.id` by looking up the values across the tables.

#### Workaround

I altered `temp_zip_type` and added an integer column called `temp_type_id`. I got the results I wanted by executing the following queries:

```
UPDATE
    temp_zip_type
SET
    temp_type_id =
    (
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            zip_code_type
        WHERE
            temp_type = value
    );


UPDATE
    zip_code
SET
    type_id =
    (
        SELECT
            temp_type_id
        FROM
            temp_zip_type
        WHERE
            zip_5_digit = temp_zip
    );
```

For future reference, is there a more efficient query? These queries took 147 seconds to complete.

Comment: The explanation seems more complicated than it has to be. To top it off, there is no `temp_type_id` in your table definition.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I forgot to mention I altered the table to get my queries to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`FROM` clause of `UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html) to join `temp_zip_type` and `zip_code_type` and do it all in one simple statement:

```
UPDATE zip_code z
SET    type_id = t.id
FROM   temp_zip_type tmp
JOIN   zip_code_type t ON t.value = tmp.temp_type
WHERE  z.zip_5_digit = tmp.temp_zip
AND    z.type_id IS DISTINCT FROM t.id;  -- avoid empty updates
```

I added the last line to avoid empty updates. It may or may not be useful. Details:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)